# Audio session .ended isn't called with two AVPlayers

Tags: objective-c, swift, avfoundation, avplayer

Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Activate `AVAudioSession` with `.playback` category.
2. Register for `AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification`
3. Create two `AVPlayer`s and start them
4. Interrupt playback by calling Siri/receiving a call by Skype, Cellular and etc.

**Expected behavior:**
Receiving notification of the audio session interruption with `.began` state at the start and `.ended` at the end. Also, as a side effect, Siri doesn't respond to commands.

**Real behavior:**
Only `.began` notification is called.

To bring back `.ended` notification (which is used to continue playback) remove one player.

**Question:** how to handle the audio session interruption with more than 1 AVPlayer running?

Here I created a simple demo project: https://github.com/denis-obukhov/AVAudioSessionBug

Tested on iOS 14.4

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  private let player1: AVPlayer? = {
    $0.volume = 0.5
    return $0
  }(AVPlayer())

  private let player2: AVPlayer? = {
    $0.volume = 0.5
    return $0 // return nil for any player to bring back .ended interruption notification
  }(AVPlayer())

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    registerObservers()
    startAudioSession()
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    player1?.replaceCurrentItem(with: makePlayerItem(named: "music1"))
    player2?.replaceCurrentItem(with: makePlayerItem(named: "music2"))
    [player1, player2].forEach { $0?.play() }
  }

  private func makePlayerItem(named name: String) -> AVPlayerItem {
    let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(
      forResource: name,
      withExtension: "mp3"
    )!
    return AVPlayerItem(url: fileURL)
  }

  private func registerObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self, selector: #selector(handleInterruption(_:)),
      name: AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification,
      object: nil
    )
  }

  private func startAudioSession() {
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback)
    try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
  }

  @objc private func handleInterruption(_ notification: Notification) {
    print("GOT INTERRUPTION")
    guard
      let userInfo = notification.userInfo,
      let typeValue = userInfo[AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as? UInt,
      let type = AVAudioSession.InterruptionType(rawValue: typeValue)
    else {
      return
    }

    switch type {
    case .began:
      print("Interruption BEGAN")
      [player1, player2].forEach { $0?.pause() }
    case .ended:
      // This part isn't called if more than 1 player is playing
      print("Interruption ENDED")
      [player1, player2].forEach { $0?.play() }
    @unknown default:
      print("Unknown value")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code that illustrates that you registered `AVAudioSession.interruptNotification` on 2 `AVPlayer`'s? It could be a simple logical error that you did, but none of us can see that. Please provide reproducable code.

Comment: @impression7vx I've provided a link to a repo with demo project. Ok, I pasted the code straight to the message.

Comment: Under your `else {` and when you do an interruption, see if it hits the `return` statement, thus nothing under it would be executed... Also, provided that, can we get a series of print statements with executions? "Interruption Began" "Got Interruption" "Interruption Ended" etc

Comment: @impression7vx No. It never hits `return` statement. Also, to check this case I have `print("GOT INTERRUPTION")` at the top or everything

Comment: https://rb.gy/opj0n5 and https://rb.gy/e6s5xl kindly check the video and get your fixed project.

Thanks

Comment: @SumitsinghThanks for trying. But it still doesn't work. So, you just changed the order of the players in the array. Sometimes .ended event is called, but most often not. https://youtu.be/cy1qdcAjtaA

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue, and it was driving me crazy for a few days. I'm using two `AVQueuePlayer` (a subclass of `AVPlayer`) to play two sets of audio sounds on top of each other, and I get the `AVAudioSession.interruptionNotification` value of `.began` when there is an incoming call, but there is no `.ended` notification when the call ends.

That said, I've found that for some reason, `.ended` is reliably sent if you instead use two instances of `AVAudioPlayer`. It also works with one instance of `AVAudioPlayer` mixed with another instance of `AVQueuePlayer`. But for some reason using two instances of `AVQueuePlayer` (or `AVPlayer`) seems to break it.

Did you ever find a solution for this? For my purposes I need queuing of tracks so I must use `AVQueuePlayer`, so I'll probably file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: No, I don't have a solution. Btw I also can't switch to AVAudioPlayer because I need to change HTTP headers accessing resources using AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey which is impossible for AVAudioPlayer.